# How to use Kotlin's invoke operator to get a receiver on object instantiation

Tags: kotlin, dsl

```
class Family() {
    fun addMember(name: String) {}

    inline operator fun invoke(body: Family.() -> Unit) {
        body()
    }
}
```

After using invoke operator function I can do something like this:

```
val family = Family().invoke { this:
    addMember("Android")
}
```

I have seen code structures where the declaration is simply by doing this.

```
val family = Family { this:
        addMember("Android")
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In current situation invoke can be called on a instance i.e.

```kotlin
val family = Family()

family {
    addMember(...)
}
```

If I understood correctly you want to create a new instance of Family and apply the block into the object, you can do this by putting the function under a companion.

```kotlin
class Family {
    fun addMember(name: String) {}

    companion object {
        inline operator fun invoke(body: Family.() -> Unit): Family {
            return Family().apply(body)
        }
    }
}
```

Now:

```kotlin
val family = Family {
    addMember(...)
}
```